# NumPy: 2D array from a list of arrays and scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scalar

I need to create a 2D numpy array from a list of 1D arrays and scalars so that the scalars are replicated to match the length of the 1D arrays.

*Example of desired behaviour*

```
>>> x = np.ones(5)
>>> something([x, 0, x])
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

I know that the vectorial elements of the list are always going to have the same length (shape) so I can do it "by hand" by doing something like this:

```
def something(lst):
    for e in lst:
        if isinstance(e, np.ndarray):
            l = len(e)
            break
    tmp = []
    for e in lst:
        if isinstance(e, np.ndarray):
            tmp.append(e)
            l = len(e)
        else:
            tmp.append(np.empty(l))
            tmp[-1][:] = e
    return np.array(tmp)
```

What I am asking for is whether there is some ready-made solution hidden somewhere in numpy or, if there is none, whether there is a better (e.g. more general, more reliable, faster) solution than the one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [179]: np.column_stack(np.broadcast(x, 0, x))
Out[179]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

or

```
In [187]: np.row_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(x, 0, x))
Out[187]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

---

Using `np.broadcast` is faster than `np.broadcast_arrays`:

```
In [195]: %timeit np.column_stack(np.broadcast(*[x, 0, x]*10))
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.4 µs per loop

In [196]: %timeit np.row_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(*[x, 0, x]*10))
1000 loops, best of 3: 380 µs per loop
```

but slower than your `something` function:

```
In [201]: %timeit something([x, 0, x]*10)
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.3 µs per loop
```

---

Note that `np.broadcast` can be passed at most 32 arrays:

```
In [199]: np.column_stack(np.broadcast(*[x, 0, x]*100))
ValueError: Need at least two and fewer than (32) array objects.
```

whereas `np.broadcast_arrays` is unlimited:

```
In [198]: np.row_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(*[x, 0, x]*100))
Out[198]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

---

Using `np.broadcast` or `np.broadcast_arrays` is a bit more general than
`something`. It will work on arrays of different (but broadcastable) shapes, for
instance:

```
In [209]: np.column_stack(np.broadcast(*[np.atleast_2d(x), 0, x]))
Out[209]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

whereas `something([np.atleast_2d(x), 0, x])` returns:

```
In [211]: something([np.atleast_2d(x), 0, x])
Out[211]: 
array([array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([ 0.]),
       array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way, but I doubt if faster:

```
l = len(max(lst, key=lambda e: len(e) if isinstance(e, np.ndarray) else 0))
new_lst = np.array([(x if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) else np.ones(l) * x) for x in lst])
```

Edit: use `np.fromiter` to do it faster:

```
l = len(max(lst, key=lambda e: len(e) if isinstance(e, np.ndarray) else 0))
new_lst = np.fromiter(((x if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) else np.ones(l) * x) for x in lst))
```

And use while loop to do it faster, but code is bit longer:

```
i = 0
while not isinstance(lst[i], np.ndarray):
  i += 1
l = len(lst[i])
new_lst = np.fromiter(((x if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) else np.ones(l) * x) for x in lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

For 25 rows, a list comprehension version of `something` is between `broadcase` and `broadcast_arrays` in speed:

```
In [48]: ll=[x,0,x,x,0]*5

In [49]: np.vstack([y if isinstance(y,np.ndarray) else np.zeros(5) for y in ll]).shape
Out[49]: (25, 5)

In [50]: timeit np.vstack([y if isinstance(y,np.ndarray) else np.zeros(5) for y in ll]).shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 219 us per loop

In [51]: timeit np.vstack(np.broadcast_arrays(*ll))
1000 loops, best of 3: 790 us per loop

In [52]: timeit np.column_stack(np.broadcast(*ll)).shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 us per loop
```

Using `np.array` instead of `vstack` it gets even better:

```
In [54]: timeit np.array([y if isinstance(y,np.ndarray) else np.zeros(5) for y in ll]).shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 54.2 us per loop
```

---

For 2d `x`, `vstack` on the `if` comprehension may be the only correct one:

```
In [66]: x=np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)

In [67]: ll=[x,0,x,x,0]

In [68]: np.vstack([y if isinstance(y,np.ndarray) else np.zeros(5) for y in ll]) 
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```